# Scope of dimension parameters of outside-of-class defined matrix

Tags: c++

Say I have the following code

```
class C {
    static const int dim = 3;
    static const int matrix[dim][dim];
};



int dim = -2;
const int C::matrix[dim][C::dim] = {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}};
```

1. Why am I obliged to state the dimensions of the matrix again?
2. Why does the first dim = 3 and not -2?

My research has shown me interesting stuff (like initialization != definition) but I haven't found this info in the C++ standard.

Comment: `error: ‘int C::matrix [3][3]’ is not a static data member of ‘class C’` You can type basically anything, but not everything is valid C++

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I suspect that you are using VC++ ( or Visual Studio IDE)

Comment: For question 2, `::dim` is not the same variable as `C::dim`.  Variables with the same name can exist in different scopes and they can all have different values.

Comment: @ChristmasTree In `C`, `C::dim` is the `dim` that is scope so just using `dim` there refers to `C::dim`.  Outside of `C`, the global `dim` (`::dim`) is the `dim` that is in scope and so using `dim` uses `::dim`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I obliged to state the dimensions of the matrix again?

Because that is part of the type. `matrix` is an object of type `const int [3][3]`

> Why does the first dim = 3 and not -2?

You are defining a member of `C`, so name lookup finds `C::dim` before it looks in `::`.